# Type mismatch error in result type

Tags: f#

I was playing around with writing a result type and assorted functions, and came across a type mismatch error I cannot explain. Here is a minimum example:

```
type ('a, 'b) result =
    | Success of 'a
    | Failure of 'b list

let apply fr xr =
    match fr, xr with
    | Success f, Success x -> Success (f x)
    | Failure _, Success _ -> fr
    | Success _, Failure _ -> xr
    | Failure a, Failure b -> Failure (List.concat [a; b])
```

Compiling this code produces the following error:

```
init.fsx(8,31): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
('a,'b) result
but given a
(('c -> 'a),'d) result
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b -> 'a'
```

If you change the *apply* function according to the below, it compiles correctly:

```
let apply fr xr =
    match fr, xr with
    | Success f, Success x -> Success (f x)
    | Failure a, Success _ -> Failure a
    | Success _, Failure b -> Failure b
    | Failure a, Failure b -> Failure (List.concat [a; b])
```

Why does using the matched over value (here *fr* or *xr*) not work but constructing a new *Failure* value does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The critical thing to understand here is that the type of a discriminated union concerns all its cases. Even if you "only" reuse instances of `Failure` from a function parameter as a return value, *all* return values, *including* the `Success` cases, must have the same type as this parameter.

Thus, using `fr` and `xr` as return values constrains their types to be identical to `apply`'s return type.

But there's also the line that takes a parameter of `Success f` to a return value of `Success (f x)`! If these two are to have the same type, the type of `f x` must be the type of `f`! That's a function that returns a function of its own type, no matter how many times you apply it; such an infinite type isn't allowed and causes the compiler error.

By building new instances for the return values, you allow `apply`'s return type to differ from its parameters' types. Then, the compiler can give `f` and its return value different types, avoiding the infinite function type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the error.

In this line:

```
Success f, Success x -> Success (f x)
```

you define `'a` to be a function type and as a result your return `'a` is also a function.

but when you do

```
| Failure _, Success _ -> fr
```

this `fr` has the same function type, but here is unapplied.

In contrast, creating the new object gives it a new type which can use the fact that the success type is now the result of the function in the second case

Comment: Thank you John. It is not clear to me why the first match alternative

`| Success f, Success x -> Success (f x)`

should have any bearing on the second match alternative

`| Failure _, Success _ -> fr`

Sounds to me like an unnecessary restriction in the compiler…

Comment: The problem is that `fr` has a different type to `Success (f x)` and an expression needs to return variables with the same type.